# Python convert dataframe in list of string with label

Tags: string, python-3.x, dataframe, type-conversion, label

I tried to convert a dataframe that contains string with his label.

Dataframe :

```
Gender    Text
male    i felt like they were my friends.
female  i absolutely adore when louis starts the sun
```

I would like this format :

```
data = [('i felt like they were my friends.', 'male'),
        ('i absolutely adore when louis starts the sun','female')]
```

**I tried this solution :**

1 - Convert in string

```
df = df['text'].astype(str).values.tolist()
```

2 - Add labels

```
dfm = [(x, y) for x in [df] for y in ["male"]]
```

But I get this :

```
[(['i felt like they were my friends.',
   'i absolutely adore when louis starts the sun'],
  'male')]
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A convenience function I like to use is `to_records`:

```
df.reindex(columns=['Text', 'Gender']).to_records(index=False).tolist()    
[
    ('i felt like they were my friends.', 'male'),
    ('i absolutely adore when louis starts the sun', 'female')
]
```

Comment: Thanks, I forget to say that my entire dataframe contains 1200 rows.

Comment: @LaurentCesaro Why should that be a problem?